# How can I add a red border to this box (an a tag) when the mouse is on (hover) the box?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am working on this template: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/

As you can see, under the header slideshow, I have 3 boxes (named respectively as **La Situazione**, **Archivio* and **Archivio Video**)

This is the code snippet of one of these box:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box-progetto">
            <h3 class="text-center">La Situazione</h3>
            <!--<p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></p>-->
            <p class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/icona-situazione-big.gif" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
            </p>
            <p>
                La situazione in sintesi: situazione politica dell'Eritrea           
            </p>
            <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block upper-botton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Visita Archivio Attività</a>-->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
</a>
```

and this is the related CSS of the **hovered** previous box (when the user pass the mouse on the box):

```
.upper-botton:hover, 
.upper-botton:focus, 
.upper-botton:active, 
.upper-botton.active, 
.open 
.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary, 
.box-progetto:hover {
   color: #990000;
   background-color: #FBE7B3;
   border-color: #990000;
   border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

My problem is that I want add a red border arround the box when the mouse is on the box. So, as you can see in the previous snippet, I tried to add these line:

```
border-color: #990000;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
```

But this seems not work.

How can I fix this issue and add a red border when the mouse is on the box?

Tnx

Comment: You need to set a `border-style` as well … without it, no border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **`border: 2px solid #990000;`**, it was not working because you need to specify the border style as well, like solid, dashed, etc. You can see a list below.

All border styles types here at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/djwf0L60/

**GET RID OF**

```
.upper-botton:hover, .upper-botton:focus, .upper-botton:active, .upper-botton.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary, .box-progetto:hover {
    border-color: #990000;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

and **REPLACE WITH**

```
.upper-botton:hover, .upper-botton:focus, .upper-botton:active, .upper-botton.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary, .box-progetto:hover {
    border: 2px solid #990000;
}
```